# The JXDatePicker Returns Wrong Date

Tags: java, swing, datepicker, simpledateformat

I am using The JXDatePicker in my Swing Application, and uses the following code to set the Date Value to the SQL Server Table

```
 Date date = jDatePicker1.getDate();          
 String expectedPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS";
 String currentFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS";
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormatReq = new SimpleDateFormat(expectedPattern);
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormatCurr = new SimpleDateFormat(currentFormat);
 String strDate = dateFormatReq.format(dateFormatCurr.parse(dateFormatCurr.format(date)));
```

The problem is that the strDate value is **'2011-04-01 12:00:00.000'**

where as my requirement is **'2011-04-01 00:00:00.000'**

Any Help in the matter will be highly appreciable.

Comment: that's not a problem of the datepicker - a date is a date :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `HH` instead of `hh` for hours. Because `HH` is "Hour in day (0-23)" and `hh` is "Hour in am/pm (1-12)".
See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html.

Comment: you must give my qs upvote as i accepted your answer @Aleksandr M